# Past Perfect Confusion

Tags: tenses, sentence, past-perfect, simple-past

In a book these two forms are acceptable:

> Before a complete version of Louisa May Alcott's novel *Little Women* appeared in 1880, the book **had been published** in two separate volumes.

AND

> Before a complete version of Louisa May Alcott's novel *Little Women* appeared in 1880, the book **was published** in two separate volumes.

I do not quite understand why both are acceptable. However I decided to just **follow it**. So I started working on other problems for practice and this is where all the confusion stems from.

> By the time Pearl S. Buck was awarded the Nobel Prize for Literature in 1938, she **was** a best-selling author in the United States for nearly a decade.

So using the general rule for **Past Perfect**, I said **had been**. And that, it turns out, is correct. However, since I was bored, I thought: **Why cannot it be *was*?** Since the rule provided above accepts either the **Simple Past** or **Past Perfect**?

So, is there anyone who can confirm why, for the first example both the **Simple Past** & **Past Perfect** can be used without error? And also, why when we come to the second example **"was"** does not work?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In the last example, you use a simple past to describe something that took place over a continuous period (*was...for nearly a decade*) and was still going on by the time the "main" event happened (*was awarded*). Normally, you can't use a simple past for this. In your first example, there is less of a notion of a continuous period up to the main event. That is my preliminary explanation of the apparent discrepancy.

Comment: In your second exmpla

Answer (score 1):

In the **first** example you give, both ***had been*** and ***was*** could be used, but they mean slightly different things.

*Before I was a teacher I was a student.* The implied suggestion here is that I was a student immediately before I became a teacher, or at least my having been a student had something to do with my becoming a teacher.

*Before I was a teacher I had been a student*. There is no suggestion here that my being a student had immediately preceded my being a teacher, nor had anything to do with it.

In the **second** example you could use the simple past, provided you dropped the words 'for nearly a decade'. In such a *by the time* expression it is not idiomatic to use a continuous past tense where you relate it to a specific time period.

*By the time he awoke I had been working for two hours*; is idiomatic.

*By the time he awoke I was working*; is idiomatic.

*By the time he awoke I was working for two hours*; is NOT idiomatic.

I think if you study those examples carefully you will understand why. 'The time he awoke' is a fixed moment - and I cannot be doing something continuously for two hours at a fixed moment.

Comment: I still do not understand what you said at the end. What do you mean by a *fixed moment*?